# CABasicAnimation for a CAShapeLayer disappears before it completes, and doesn't continue infinitely

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, core-animation, calayer

I'm trying to create an infinitely tracing path that draws and the back of it disappears. However, the code I have makes the path disappear after a single iteration. In fact, the layer disappears before the path's disappear animation completes. It seems like, instead, it disappears when the drawing animation completes.

Furthermore, once it disappears, it doesn't show up again for another few seconds (perhaps however long it would take for the animation to repeat) before starting again.

Two questions:

1. Why is the layer disappearing before the disappearing animation completes?
2. How can I make the animation play continuously without disappearing?

Thank you in advance! Here's my code:

```
CGRect boundingFrame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds) - 48.0, CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds) - 48.0, 96.0, 96.0);

_pathPoints = @[
                 [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(boundingFrame), CGRectGetMinY(boundingFrame) + squareSideWidth/2.0)],
                 [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(boundingFrame) + squareSideWidth/2.0, CGRectGetMidY(boundingFrame))],
                 [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(boundingFrame), CGRectGetMaxY(boundingFrame) - squareSideWidth/2.0)],
                 [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(boundingFrame) - squareSideWidth/2.0, CGRectGetMidY(boundingFrame))]
                ];

CAShapeLayer *line = [CAShapeLayer layer];
line.path = pathForPoints(_pathPoints).CGPath;
line.lineCap = kCALineCapRound;
line.strokeColor = color.CGColor;
line.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
line.strokeEnd = 0.0;
[self.layer addSublayer:line];

NSMutableArray<CABasicAnimation *> *animations = [NSMutableArray new];
for (int i = 0; i < [_pathPoints count]; i++) {
    CABasicAnimation *drawAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
    drawAnimation.beginTime = index;
    drawAnimation.duration = 1.0;
    drawAnimation.fromValue = @(strokeEndForIndex(points, index - 1));
    drawAnimation.toValue = @(strokeEndForIndex(points, index));
    drawAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    drawAnimation.additive = YES;
    drawAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;

    CABasicAnimation *eraseAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeStart"];
    eraseAnimation.beginTime = index + 0.75;
    eraseAnimation.duration = 1.0;
    eraseAnimation.fromValue = @(strokeEndForIndex(points, index - 1));
    eraseAnimation.toValue = @(strokeEndForIndex(points, index));
    eraseAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    eraseAnimation.additive = YES;
    eraseAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;

    CAAnimationGroup *group = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
    group.animations = @[drawAnimation, eraseAnimation];
    group.duration = 2.0 * [animations count];
    group.repeatCount = INFINITY;
    group.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    [line addAnimation:group forKey:@"line"];
}
```

Helper functions, for reference:

```
static CGFloat lengthOfPathWithPoints(NSArray<NSValue *> *points)
{
    CGFloat totalDist = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < [points count]; i++) {
        CGFloat xDist = [points[i % [points count]] CGPointValue].x - [points[(i + 1) % [points count]] CGPointValue].x;
        CGFloat yDist = [points[i % [points count]] CGPointValue].y - [points[(i + 1) % [points count]] CGPointValue].y;
        totalDist += sqrt(pow(xDist, 2) + pow(yDist, 2));
    }
    return totalDist;
}

static CGFloat strokeEndForIndex(NSArray<NSValue *> *points, int index)
{
    // If it's the last index, just return 1 early
    if (index == [points count] - 1) {
        return 1.0;
    }
    // In the case where index = -1 (as it does for the initial erase animation fromValue), just return 0
    if (index < 0) {
        return 0.0;
    }

    CGFloat totalDist = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < index + 1; i++) {
        CGFloat xDist = [points[i % [points count]] CGPointValue].x - [points[(i + 1) % [points count]] CGPointValue].x;
        CGFloat yDist = [points[i % [points count]] CGPointValue].y - [points[(i + 1) % [points count]] CGPointValue].y;
        totalDist += sqrt(pow(xDist, 2) + pow(yDist, 2));
    }

    return totalDist/lengthOfPathWithPoints(points);
}

static UIBezierPath *pathForPoints(NSArray<NSValue *> *points)
{
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath new];
    [path moveToPoint:[[points firstObject] CGPointValue]];
    for (int i = 0; i < [points count]; i++) {
        [path addLineToPoint:[points[(i + 1) % 4] CGPointValue]];
    }
    return path;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Increase your duration property value and change your repeatCount = Float(Int.max) to something like this.

Comment: Thanks! Gave this a shot, didn't have any luck with it.